# Why Not open the dialog box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Why doesn't Open the dialog box "elete-dialog2" when running the line in bold (between **)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var deleteLinkObj;
        // delete Link
        $('.delete-link').click(function () {
            deleteLinkObj = $(this);  //for future use
            $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
            return false; // prevents the default behaviour
        });

        //definition of the delete dialog.
        $('#delete-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false, width: 350, resizable: false, modal: true, //Dialog options
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data) {  //Post to action
                        if (data == '@Boolean.TrueString') {
                            deleteLinkObj.closest("tr").hide('slow'); //Hide Row
                            //(optional) Display Confirmation
                        }
                       else {
                            //this is the line
                            **$('#delete-dialog2').dialog('open');**
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
 $('#delete-dialog2').dialog({
            autoOpen: false, width: 350, resizable: false, modal: true, //Dialog options
            buttons: {

                "Accept": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

The view:

```
<h2>UNIVERSITIES</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.IdUniversidad }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.IdUniversidad }, new { @class = "delete-link" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<div id="delete-dialog" title="Information">
<p>Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>
</div>  

<div id="delete-dialog2" title="Error">
<p>Ooops... Something failed</p>
</div>
```

It only shows the dialog with confirm and cancel buttons, but when trying to show cuandro, the dialog with the accept button is not shown

First if opened ('#delete-dialog'), not open the second dialog ('#delete-dialog2') when the execution enter to else the execution enter to else in this part `if (data == '@Boolean.TrueString') { deleteLinkObj.closest("tr").hide('slow'); //Hide Row //(optional) Display Confirmation } else { **$('#delete-dialog2').dialog('open');** }`

Blessings

Comment: The rendered HTML is more useful for debugging what seems to be mainly a JavaScript issue; parsing the asp.net view to see what "would" be rendered is something I for one would rather avoid. I don't THINK most of it is consequential (the dialog divs are there and visible) but you never know.

Comment: ensure you're adding your js at end of page, otherwise, what may be happening is your js is rendering in full before the actual element exist

Comment: @SpYk3HH The JS functions are wrapped in the document.ready function, so the page should be rendered. Content brought in by Ajax is another story, but the samples show a rendered page rather than an Ajax-requested page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick test seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/bES2X/1/

There are two things different from yours:

1. The exact markup used. I kinda guessed a bit. If I understand your ASP.NET code correctly, you might be using multiple IDs for your rows, which is invalid markup.
2. The $post function (I just hardcoded a failing scenario). It seems like the href will evaluate correctly *IF* what you want is the HREF of the first data-link. So then is the conditional for `@Boolean.TrueString` working out? Try watching this expression or console.log to test.